# ClassNotFoundException android after copy a class from one app to another one

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I am programming two applications; I have used some Classes from one of these applications into the other one. When I tried to instance the class it shows ClassNotFoundException. (It’s not an Activity Class) when it show me the error I notice that the path to the class it has used is from the first app. The Class is inside my new app package. What can i do? Help me please

Comment: Check your imports. Is the R file import correct?


It should be `com.abc.newapp.R` instead of `com.abc.oldapp.R`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvius but, if you copied the files directly in the filesyste (outside eclipse) you have to do a File Refresh and then a Project clean inside eclipse for it to take the changes.

If you copied the classes inside eclipse, check that the import statements where you are using the classes are ok (referencing the correct project).